# Read in Jeanne Boyarsky and Scott Selikoff's book for OCP-11 1z0-815 page-57: Java is not case sensitive. Is that true?

Tags: java

I cannot seem to wrap my head around this text. Could anyone please enlighten me regarding this?

[image: Jeanne Boyarsky and Scott Selikoff OCP-11 1z0-815 page number 57]

Comment: Looks like a typo, or I am not following.

Comment: Yeah that's a runaway "not".

Comment: java IS case sensitive https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity

Comment: But guys if you notice lines following the highlighted part, it actually explains why case insensitivity led to the compilation of that code snippet. Although, Jeanne Boyarsky and Scott Selikoff are quite well renowned Java engineers. I think they know what they have written, so it's not a typo. I think it is having a different context which hasn't been explicitly mentioned here.

Comment: @ShayanAhmad No, this is definitely a typo (as also mentioned by sainaen's answer). Java is case-sensitive, so `Var` and `var` are simply two different things, just like `a` and `b` would be. I think you misunderstood that part. Case-sensitivity means that `Var` is not the same as `var`, which is not the same as *different meanings in different contexts*. The one is about synonyms, the other aboit homonyms.

Answer (score 3):

It is not true.

[The page for the book](https://www.selikoff.net/ocp11-1/) on Scott’s website has an errata section which lists this sentence as an error:

> Page 57 — In the second paragraph, it says “Java is not case sensitive”. This should [be] “Java is case sensitive”